# Span-Elements in FormattedString appear to be trimmed

Tags: c#, xamarin, label, xamarin.forms

I am trying to put some formatted text in a view (an imprint, for what it's worth) with a Label with an formatted text. Text formatting works as intended, but whenever I try to add whitespace characters to the end of a span element within the formatted text these appear to be trimmed. This holds true for normal spaces, non-breaking spaces and CR/NL so far. Anyway, when in the middle of a string, nothing is removed.

This renders the label unusable for me (at least for this use-case), since I won't be able to format my text properly. Is there anything I have missed? I did not find anything about this matter in the web and in the documentation. Is the approach taken completely wrong, or is this a bug in Xamarin? (For that matter, the version used is 2.3.2.127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This renders the label unusable for me (at least for this use-case), since I won't be able to format my text properly

It's not entirely clear why you would try to achieve this formatting with trailing whitespace.

Have you tried using margin or padding around the label?

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding/

Using whitespace characters for element spacing is generally not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to use inline `Text="..."` rather than enclosing the text between an opening and closing tag.  For example, this preserves the spaces:

```
<FormattedString.Spans>
    <Span Text="You have " />
    <Span Text="{Binding Points}"  />
    <Span Text=" points." />
</FormattedString.Spans>
```

But this trims whitespace:

```
<FormattedString.Spans>
    <Span>You have </Span>
    <Span Text="{Binding Points}"  />
    <Span> points.</Span>
</FormattedString.Spans>
```

Comment: Note that there is some limitation. For example, a Span with multiple spaces displays as if there were only one, even when entered as `Text="    "`.